# Using multiple data sets in populate_page_with in page-object gem

Tags: ruby, cucumber, page-object-gem

I have a form that I populate with populate_page_with data_for using the page-object gem. It is defined this way:

```
def add_fruit(data = {})
  populate_page_with data_for(:new_fruit, data)
  add_fruit_submit
end
```

Then I call the method in my step this way:

```
on(AddFruitPage).add_fruit
```

My yml file looks like this:

```
new_fruit:
  color: red
  size: large
  type: apple
  price: 0.75
  ...
another_fruit
  color: orange
  size: medium
  type: orange
  price: 0.99
  ...
```

I know that I can overwrite each of these fields by doing something like this in my step:

```
When(^/I add a banana$/) do
  on(AddFruitPage).add_fruit('color' => 'yellow', 'size' => 'small', 'type' => 'banana')
end
```

Since the data for another fruit is already in the yml file, can I use a parameter to tell the method which data to load rather than having to specify each value when I use the method? Something like:

```
def add_fruit(data = {})
  if(data['type'] == 'another')
    populate_page_with data_for(:new_fruit, data)
  else
    populate_page_with data_for(:another_fruit, data)
  end
end
```

And call it this way?

```
on(AddFruitPage).add_fruit('type' => 'another')
```

Type is an optional parameter that would only be used to load another set of data. Color, size, type, and price all map to text fields on the page that are defined in the class. Is it possible to do something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Ruby 2, you could used named parameters - creating a named parameter for the fruit type and the rest as being part of the data array.

Instead of using a 'type', which already exists in the data, I would probably use a parameter that specifies the first parameter of the `data_for`. The method definition would simply be:

```
def add_fruit(fruit_type: :new_fruit, **data)
  populate_page_with data_for(fruit_type, data)
  add_fruit_submit
end
```

Which could be called in variety of ways:

```
add_fruit()  # Specify nothing
add_fruit(:color => 'red')  # Just specify the data
add_fruit(:fruit_type => :another_fruit)  # Just specify the fruit type
add_fruit(:fruit_type => :another_fruit, :color => 'red')  # Specify fruit type and data
```

If you are using a version prior to Ruby 2, you can do the same with:

```
def add_fruit(data = {})
  fruit_type = data.delete(:fruit_type) || :new_fruit
  populate_page_with data_for(fruit_type, data)
  add_fruit_submit
end
```

Comment: I am using ruby 1.9.3. Would I call it with add_fruit(:fruit_type => :another_fruit)?

Comment: The two versions of the method do the same thing. So yes, you could call the method that way (plus the other examples).

Comment: Thanks Justin. Appreciate the help.